# Реализовать конструкцию IF ELSE mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT id_hours, date, hours, id_voditeli, id_tehnika, id_service,
(hours*200) AS earned
FROM worked_hours
WHERE id_voditeli=16
```

Как сделать так чтобы если `id_service=1` то значение было `(hours*200)`, а
если `id_service=2` то значение `(hours*250)`?

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/loops/if_then.php

Comment: `(hours*(200+50*(id_service-1))) AS earned`

Comment: RTFM 'CASE operator', https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Answer (score 2):

MySQL поддерживает конструкцию CASE. Что важно - это конструкция чистого стандартного SQL и может применяться без создания хранимых процедур. Кстати не только в MySQL, но практически в любой БД.

```
CASE id_service
  WHEN 1 THEN hours*200
  ELSE hours*250
END AS earned
```

Я накидал Вам аналог IF ELSE, который Вы просили. Его можно вставлять прямо в запрос. Но обратите внимание, что вторая ветка отработает на ЛЮБОЕ значение кроме 1, а не только на 2. Если в столбце `id_service` возможно появление какого-то другого значения, то значение 2 надо явно обработать с помощью WHEN, а в ветке ELSE обрабатывать уже все другие значения.
P.S. Ну и в комментариях к вопросу был очень остроумный вариант с формулой)